# SharePoint Server 2010 upgrade: An error occurred while enabling Enterprise features

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, upgrade

While trying to upgrade from SharePoint Server 2010 to SharePoint Enterprise 2010, I kept getting the following blocking error:

> An error occurred while enabling Enterprise features. Refer to the event logs on your server machines for more details.

This happened to me on a testing server where SharePoint is installed on the domain controller together with the SQL database.

ULS Log notifications are:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Administration.SkuUpgradeJobException: Post setup configuration failed when attempting post setup configuration task -cmd services -install -cmd installfeatures
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Administration.SkuUpgradeJob.Execute(SPJobState jobState)

and

> Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14, 044806dd "sharepoint server", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", b457b5a8 "microsoft.sharepoint.portal", 0e0017da "14.0.6106.0", 4df9c44e "thu jun 16 10:52:30 2011", 00003b09 "00003b09", 00000205 "00000205", 5f425cf0 "skuupgradejobexception", 38696c35 "8il5"

and

> The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Administration.SkuUpgradeJob(ID 6bc45835-8c56-478a-b80b-b4377cc2260d) threw an exception. More information is included below.
>   Post setup configuration failed when attempting post setup configuration task -cmd services -install -cmd installfeatures

and

> Exception stack trace:
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Administration.SkuUpgradeJob.Execute(SPJobStatejobState)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this error by changing the SharePoint 2010 Timer account to a local administrator account.

At first it was configured to use my SharePoint Farm Account "SP_Farm". I changed the SharePoint 2010 Timer account to log on as "Local System" and retried upgrading the SharePoint license. This time it worked.

After the upgrade I reconfigured the SharePoint 2010 Timer account to log on as SP_Farm.